# creating multiple .gitconfig

Tags: eclipse, git

I am new to Git.
I have gone through couple of on-line tutorials. I want to do some hands on to understand it better.
I am using eclipse EGit plug in(not installed git in the system).
I created a git remote repository and added 2 users for the project.
Now I want to try out things in eclipse, but I am facing a problem.
I have 2 eclipse instance in my system, I want to use it for each git user.
But the problem is both are pointing to same .gitconfig file.
So I can't use it for 2 users.
Could any one please help how to create multiple .gitconfig?

Thanks in advance.
Kitty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to achieve this.

1. Make it look like there are two users on the machine. Set `$HOME` to different values and launch each eclipse instance with a different setting.
2. Don't use the `$HOME/.gitconfig` at all and configure everything per repository. To change settings, go to *Preferences* -> *Team* -> *Git* -> *Configuration* and then change settings in the *Repository Settings* tab.

   For this section option, you may want to clone the same repository twice. To do that you need to give a new directory name on the last page of the clone wizard:

[image]